# Чат-бот ВК отвечает только один раз

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

```
r_id = datetime.timestamp(datetime.now())
    def write_msg(user_id, message):
        vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id': user_id, 'message': message, 'random_id': r_id}) # r_id - всегда разный
    def get_msg(user_id):
        msg = vk_session.method('messages.getHistory', {'out': 0, 'count': 1, 'time_offset': 0, 'user_id': user_id})
        return msg


vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=api_key)
vk = vk_session.get_api()
lp = VkLongPoll(vk_session)


for event in lp.listen():
    if event.to_me:
        msg_values = get_msg(event.user_id)
        print(msg_values)
        msg_user = msg_values['items'][0]['text']
        print(msg_user)
        if msg_user == '1':
            write_msg(event.user_id, 'hello')
        elif msg_user == '2':
            write_msg(event.user_id, 'bye')
```

Бот отвечает на сообщение только 1 раз, то есть если я напишу в диалог "1", он ответит, после этого я пишу "2" и он не отвечает, хотя в дебаге отображается что сообщение пришло.

UPD: изобрел велосипед напрямую с апи вконтакте, проблема в методе messages.send, почему то он срабатывает только 1 раз. Может что-то нужно передать ему еще, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Откуда берётся `r_id`? Может ли быть такое, что он одинаков для отправки первого и второго сообщений ботом?

Comment: дополнил, это рандомное число всегда

Comment: @IceCube092, `r_id` разный для каждого сообщения?

Comment: да, r_id всегда разный, я ж комментарий оставил

Comment: @IceCube092 Почему `r_id` всегда разный? Вы можете обосновать это кодом? Непонятно откуда он берётся. Для его получения в модуле `vk_api.utils` есть специальная функция `get_random_id`, но Вы её почему-то не используете.

Comment: я для его получения использую текущее время, так что там большое число рандомное

Comment: @IceCube092 Почему Вы так упорно не хотите приводить код, в котором генерируется `r_id`? Вы уверены, что там нет ошибки? Поймите, без всего кода, а точнее без _"минимального кода для воспроизведения проблемы"_ очень трудно Вам помочь. Все "симптомы" указывают на то, что `r_id` может быть одинаковый при отправке сообщений.

Comment: @nomnoms12 сделал чтоб r_id =get_random_id() из vk_api.utils
до этого r_id = datetime.timestamp(datetime.now())
ничего не изменилось, также отвечает только один раз

Comment: @IceCube092 Приведите, наконец, этот участок кода! У вас в конце скрипта бесконечный (!) цикл `for`. Каким именно образом `r_id` может поменять своё значение, если вызов функции происходит из бесконечного цикла?! Бессмысленный диалог получается: мы обсуждаем код, который видите только Вы... Последнее, что могу посоветовать — генерируйте `r_id` прямо в функции `write_msg`, используя `get_random_id`.

Comment: @nomnoms12, да Вы оказались правы, у меня r_id определялся до цикла, внес внутри цикла и заработало, спасибо!

Comment: @IceCube092 Рад помочь! :) На будущее, пожалуйста, приводите код целиком. Именно там, где казалось бы всё правильно, часто закрадывается ошибка. Проблему можно было решить гораздо быстрее. Успехов Вам! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`random_id` (`r_id`) в Вашем коде инициализируется однократно, поэтому после отправки первого сообщения в пределах сессии, ВК считает последующие дубликатами и не обрабатывает их.

Генерируйте `r_id` прямо в функции, чтобы для каждого сообщения он был **уникальный**:

```py
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id


def write_msg(user_id, message):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id': user_id, 'message': message, 'random_id': get_random_id()})
```